# Why are there only 4 fields in this Lua table? Shouldn't there be 7?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Why are there only 4 fields in this Lua table? Shouldn't there be 7?

```
   polyline = {color="blue", thickness=2, npoints=4,
                 {x=0,   y=0},
                 {x=10, y=0},
                 {x=-10, y=1},
                 {x=0,   y=1}
               }

print(table.maxn(polyline))    -- returns 4. Why?
print(polyline[2].x)   -- returns 10. Why?
```

I thought `polyline[2]` would index to "thickness", which is the 2nd field in this table.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you should reread the [table constructor operator manual](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html). To summarize, the named fields in the table (i.e. color, thickness, npoints) don't have any numerical index assigned, just the name. If you omit the name, an 1-based index is generated. Your definition of `polyline` is equivalent to this one:

```
   polyline = {
                 color="blue", thickness=2, npoints=4,
                 [1] = {x=0,   y=0},
                 [2] = {x=10, y=0},
                 [3] = {x=-10, y=1},
                 [4] = {x=0,   y=1}
               }
```

This explains the output of `print(polyline[2].x)` (also, table fields in Lua tables don't have any ordering; `pairs` is allowed to enumerate them in any order). As for [`table.maxn`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.maxn):

> [table.maxn] Returns the largest positive numerical
>   index of the given table, or zero if
>   the table has no positive numerical
>   indices. (To do its job this function
>   does a linear traversal of the whole
>   table.)

So the output is again, correct. The table really contains 7 fields, but `table.maxn` doesn't return the total number of fields at all.